# How do I plot several graphs from one DF without manually retyping the graph function each time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a DF with prices (Open) and volume for lots of different stocks on each day. I'm trying to plot the same chart for each ticker (shown below example for EZJ). However, i'd like to be able to do this for all the different tickers without having to manually isolate each ticker in a separate df and then retype the plot function. And if the Ticker's in the df change, there is no requirement to update the code.

````
Ticker  Date    Open    volume_m
EZJ 2016-01-04  17.3    1.311801
EZJ 2016-01-05  17.45   0.808658
EZJ 2016-01-06  17.64   1.027079
EZJ 2016-01-07  17.21   2.484108
EZJ 2016-01-08  16.78   1.733707
... ... ... ...
KO  2021-02-11  0.4981  21.928581
KO  2021-02-12  0.5057  13.137059
KO  2021-02-16  0.5062  15.093406
KO  2021-02-17  0.5 12.775807
KO  2021-02-18  0.5016  12.749841 



ezj_stock=stock_returns.loc['EZJ'].set_index('Date')
ezj_stock['14d_mean_price']=ezj_stock['Open'].rolling(window=14).mean()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
top.plot(ezj_stock.index, ezj_stock['Open'])
bottom.bar(ezj_stock.index, ezj_stock['volume_m']) 
top.plot(ezj_stock.index, ezj_stock['14d_mean_price'])

# set the labels
top.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
top.set_title('EZJ')
top.set_ylabel('Open_Price £', fontsize=12)
bottom.set_ylabel('Volume (mn)', fontsize=10) ```
````

Comment: Do you want all the tickers on the same graph?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by running the plotting functions in a `for` loop that goes through the list of tickers and makes it possible to select the data corresponding to each ticker in an automated way. In the following example, the data for each ticker is selected by using boolean indexing with `stocks[stocks['ticker'] == ticker]`:

```
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd              # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.2

# Create sample of random data for daily stock opening price and volume traded
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1234)  # random number generator
dti = pd.bdate_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2021-02-22')
ABC = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(ticker='ABC',
                             Open = 100 + rng.normal(size=dti.size).cumsum(),
                             volume_m = rng.uniform(0.5, 3, size=dti.size)),
                   index=dti)
XYZ = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(ticker='XYZ',
                             Open = 50 + rng.normal(size=dti.size).cumsum(),
                             volume_m = rng.uniform(0.5, 3, size=dti.size)),
                   index=dti)
stocks = pd.concat([ABC, XYZ])
stocks
```

[image: df stocks]

```
for ticker in stocks['ticker'].unique():
    stock = stocks[stocks['ticker'] == ticker].copy()
    stock.loc[:, '14d_mean_price'] = stock['Open'].rolling(window=14).mean()
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
    bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    top.plot(stock.index, stock['Open'])
    bottom.bar(stock.index, stock['volume_m'])
    top.plot(stock.index, stock['14d_mean_price'])

    # set the labels
    top.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    top.set_title(ticker)
    top.set_ylabel('Open_Price £', fontsize=12)
    bottom.set_ylabel('Volume (mn)', fontsize=10)
```

[image: ABC]

[image: XYZ]